# Xcode - Upload an Image and Set As Background

Tags: xcode

I've imported an image into Xcode using an UIImagePicker and stored it etc, but I'm unsure how to permanently change the new stored image as the apps background, if the User were to select a "Set As Background" button.

Comment: store your image in `userdefault` and app start fetch from `userdefault` simple

Comment: The data has been stored under a userdefault, I'm unsure of the coding that would allow me to set the background e.g.

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"]];



OR

UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];

Comment: edit question and past your code